# Problema con la importación de javax.persistence

Tags: java, api, jpa, maven

Comencé a programar una api rest. Todo Andaba bien hasta que para hacer las notaciones de jpa como ser @Entity, @Id, etc. No me realiza las importaciones necesarias. Tampoco me ofrece la dependencia, y si importo manualmente, por ejemplo:
 `import javax.persistence.Entity;` el intellij me devuelve: cannot resolve symbol 'persistence'.
Uso openjdk 21, Maven 3.9.4, y el IntelliJ Community Edition 2023.1.4
No tengo idea si el problea es de Maven, o de java, o de mi editor.
En el archivo pom.xml agregué la siguiente dependencia:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

y me salió la opción de javax.persistence. Lo elegí y el editor me devuelve:

```
maven:maven-model:jar:3.0.2.javadoc was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Try to run Maven import with -U flag (force update snapshots)
```

Hago lick para forzar actualizar la snapshot y me devuelve:

```
Could not find artifact maven:maven:pom:1.1.javadoc in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
Could not find artifact maven:maven:pom:1.1.javadoc in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

Por alguna razón no puede encotrar lo que le pido.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hice tantas cosas! Probé usar netbeans y tenía el mismo problema, la misma respuesta. Por lo que se me ocurrió que el problema era Java. Instalé una versión menor (la 17). Volví a correr el proyecto, borrando todas las anotaciones y luego al ponerlas de nuevo me importó todo bien y por lo menos el servidor está funcionando